# Shed Roof is Black and Has Water Damage

Tags: roof, structural, shed

my Dad's shed had a roof that he didn't take care of for a while and now appears to have rotted in several regions.

I'll provide several pictures, but the video is best: [Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r57Owlut_t8&feature=youtu.be)

What is the best way to approach a problem like this, and what would be the best solution to it. Also, what is the likely extent of the damage so far, and is this a risk to the roof failing?

Left Side:
[image: Left Side]

Right Side:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The black is bad get a screwdriver and see if the plywood is compromised. Push on the screwdriver and if it goes into the wood 1/8 “ or further the wood needs to be replaced. If it is still solid I would use a very strong solution of hydrogen peroxide and water 5-8%  and saturate all the fungus areas a second treatment may be needed but this will kill the surface fungus that will break down the plywood.

Note 8% hydrogen peroxide will bleach just about anything including your hair so use ppe. It can be applied with a paint roller or sponge, at this strength I would not spray it as I do with 3-4%.

AAA.  Always add acid to water to reduce the exothermic reaction when diluting concentrated hydrogen peroxide with water.